# Create a weekly schedule using Javascript (web application)

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm creating a weekly schedule with a row that contains columns allocated to each of the 7 days (mon, tues, wed etc).
Above that row, i want to add the date (e.g. 13/5) for each day. When the week is over, i want to update the dates. How do i do that with javascript?
The link of the image of how the weekly schedule should look like is below.
[weekly schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHLQw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ill advice u get the day of the week using new Date().getDay
 Firstly set your default date
If (new Date().setFullYear(x, y, z).getDay = 6){
    document.getElementById('...'). innerHTML=...+7

}
For each of the days (from Sunday to Saturday)

Comment: Thank you! May i know what the "+7" and x,y,z  are for?

Comment: The +7 updates the default date, and add a new week date that is 13 (today)+7=20(next week date). X,y z are the starting date for the timetable. The date u want to be present on the column. For each of the days of the week.